# Connecting with  MySQL.NET connector

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms, mysql-connector

I'm getting error:

> Could not establish a connection to database

when I connect with MySQL .NET connector. I'm fully sure of that the username is right, the password is right, the database is right, and the server is right. Here's the code:

```
mysqlCon.ConnectionString = "Server=(servername);Username=(username);Pwd=(rightpassword); 
Database=(rightdatabase)";
try
{
    mysqlCon.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not establish a connection to database!");
}
```

Comment: It migh tbe usefull to print the ex.Message instead of ignoring it. If you don't use the exception you caught, don't give it a name (e.g. use _catch(Exception)_

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use `Uid` instead of `Username`? At least [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p28) says so :)
And also check what port is your MySQL running at. You might need to add port number to your connection string if you aren't using the default one -  `3306`.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
public MySqlConnection NewConnection(string host, int port, string db, string user, string pwd)
{
    string cstr = String.Format(
        "SERVER={0};PORT={1};DATABASE={2};UID={3};PWD={4}",
        host, port, db, user, pwdd);
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cstr);
    try { conn.Open(); }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        conn = null;
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the database is reachable from the machine you're running the code.

Use telnet

```
telnet <server> 3306
```

or MySQL command line client

```
mysql -u <user> -h <server> -P <port> -p
```